# Pandas groupby on a column of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas` dataframe with a column that contains `lists`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'List': [['once', 'upon'], ['once', 'upon'], ['a', 'time'], ['there', 'was'], ['a', 'time']], 'Count': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]})

Count   List
2    [once, upon]
3    [once, upon]
4    [a, time]
1    [there, was]
2    [a, time]
```

How can I combine the `List` columns and sum the `Count` columns? The expected result is:

```
Count   List
5     [once, upon]
6     [a, time]
1     [there, was]
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby('List')['Count'].sum()
```

which results in:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to convert to tuples first. This is because `pandas.groupby` requires keys to be hashable. Tuples are immutable and hashable, but lists are not.

```
res = df.groupby(df['List'].map(tuple))['Count'].sum()
```

Result:

```
List
(a, time)       6
(once, upon)    5
(there, was)    1
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

If you need the result as lists in a dataframe, you can convert back:

```
res = df.groupby(df['List'].map(tuple))['Count'].sum()
res['List'] = res['List'].map(list)

#            List  Count
# 0     [a, time]      6
# 1  [once, upon]      5
# 2  [there, was]      1
```