# Problem about using groupby on a list column

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I'm using the MovieLens 1M dataset to learn pandas, and I want to get some data based on the genres column.

one row of the dataframe I get is like this:

```
movieid title   genres  rating  userid  gender  age occupation  zipcode timestamp
1000204 2198    Modulations (1998)  [Documentary]   5   5949    M   18  17  47901   958846401
1000205 2703    Broken Vessels (1998)   [Drama] 3   5675    M   35  14  30030   976029116
1000206 2845    White Boys (1999)   [Drama] 1   5780    M   18  17  92886   958153068
1000207 3607    One Little Indian (1973)    [Comedy, Drama, Western]    5   5851    F   18  20  55410   957756608
1000208 2909    Five Wives, Three Secretaries and Me (1998) [Documentary]   4   5938    M   25  1   35401   957273353
```

I want to us df.groupby('genres') to groupby the dataframe and then get the sum of each genre and the mean rating of each genre.

However, when I use the df.groupby('genres').mean(), it had an error 
"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' "

Please tell me why this error happeded and how can I use groupby on a column which the data are lists.

THX very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby on a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434712/pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` takes a list as argument. Try  `df.groupby(['genres']).mean()`

Comment: `groupby()` can also take a single column name as a string. The issue is the list type of the data elements, not how the groupby is being called