# Count the occurrenct of subelement in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
Tag
-----
c#|.net
javascript|html|React
python|docker
```

I need to count by `groupby_tags={'c#','.net','python'}`

How can I do it in python? Thanks.

Comment: yes, i hope to get this kind of output.

Comment: @susaanne you would like to know how many rows contain c#, how many contain python, etc...?

Comment: yes, then i guess i can do a groupby

Comment: Why do you have such data in a dataframe? Are these rows from a file? I have the feeling that you might not need at all a dataframe here.

Comment: @susanne, do you want a multiindex groupby kind of thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby on a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434712/pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists)

Comment: @susanne you can use the explode function of pandas

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with counter and itertools chain

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(list(itertools.chain(*[i.split("|") for i in df["column-name"].tolist()])))
```

1. `df["column-name"].tolist()`   gives you a list
2. Iterating and splitting each entry inside the list at "|" gives you a  list further.
3. You chain it with itertools to create a single list.
4. You can then use Counter from collections module to get the count of all items.

The counter contains how many c#, python, .net etc tags are there in total.

Approaches to groupby:

```
df[["A", "B"]] = df["column-name"].split("|", expand=True)
```

gives a dataframe like for that column

```
>>> df
   col  A  B
0  a|b  a  b
1  c|d  c  d
2  a|c  a  c
3  b|d  b  d
```

From here a groupby can be performed, by using `df.groupby(by=["A", "B"], level=0)`

Another method for groupby can be the `explode` function. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html