# How to use groupby function if I have a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column where each row is a list.  I want to use groupby in order to find maximum value of popularity by genres for each year (I have a 'year' column too). However, I get an error - unhashable type: 'list'.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby on a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434712/pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists)

Comment: If i proceed the code:

res = df.groupby(df['genres'].map(tuple))

I get an error:
'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

[pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434712/pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists)

Above solution should work unless you have any null values in **genres** columns. In that case, remove or replace null values and try again.

check for any null values by:

```
    df["genres"].isnull().sum()
```

Hope this solves your **'float' object is not iterable** error.