# DataFrame groupby on each item within a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`):

```markdown
| A   | B     | C                       |
| --- | ----- | ----------------------- |
| CA  | Jon   | [sales, engineering]    |
| NY  | Sarah | [engineering, IT]       |
| VA  | Vox   | [services, engineering] |
```

I am trying to group by each item in the `C` column list (sales, engineering, IT, etc.).

Tried:

```
df.groupby('C')
```

but got list not hashable, which is expected. I came across another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434712/pandas-groupby-on-a-column-of-lists) where it was recommended to convert the `C` column to tuple which is hashable, but I need to groupby each item and not the combination.

My goal is to get the count of each row in the `df` for each item in the `C` column list. So:

```
sales: 1
engineering: 3
IT: 1
services: 1
```

While there is probably a simpler way to obtain this than using `groupby`, I am still curious if `groupby` can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) & [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) :

```
out = df.explode("C").value_counts("C")
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

C          
engineering    3
IT             1
sales          1
services       1
dtype: int64
```